# Finding $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $\frac{n^5}{2^n}$ where $n$ is natural number

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to find $\sup A, \inf A$ where

$$A=\{a_n=\frac{n^5}{2^n}:n\in\Bbb{N}\}, 1\not\in\Bbb{N}$$

For $n=1$ we have $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n^5}{2^n}=0$ and after differentiating I found out that the critical point is at $n=\frac{5}{\ln 2}$. And there is my problem:

We know that the candidates for $\sup$ and $\inf$ are $0,\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_k, a_j$ for natural $k$, $j$ near $\frac{5}{\ln 2}$. But how to find $k$ and $j$? Clearly $\frac{5}{\ln 2}\not\in\Bbb{N}$ so $k=\lfloor\frac{5}{\ln 2}\rfloor$ and $j=\lceil\frac{5}{\ln 2}\rceil$ but how to find where $k$ and $j$ are exactly?

Comment: Find $N$ so that the sequence is decreasing for $n>N$.  It in fact decreases to zero.  Then you only have finitely many terms to look at to find the max.

Comment: your approach is correct and the max is taken when $n=7$ , for the values $k=7$ and $j=8$,

Comment: How did you find those $k$ and $j$?

Comment: by computing them see [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2Fln%282%29) for example

Comment: Is there a way for finding $k$ and $j$ without calculator?

Comment: trying all values, or using approximation for  $ln(2)=ln(1+1)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\cdots $

Answer (score 1):

Note that the critical value $\frac{5}{\ln 2}\in(7,8)$ and hence $k=\lfloor\frac{5}{\ln 2}\rfloor=7$ and $j=\lceil\frac{5}{\ln 2}\rceil=8$.  But $a_7>a_8$ and so $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_7>a_8>a_9>\cdots$ and hence $\sup\{a_n\}=a_7$ and $\inf\{a_n\}=0$.